# ReactJS - How To Block blackword in a input

Tags: reactjs

i'm new in React JS, i'm trying to remove the input value when the user inserts this in the input value, how can i get the array "Blacklist" and change remove the words in the input when typed. Thanks!!!

```js
 class BlackWordInput extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.state = {
       place: 'Digite uma palavra!'
     }
   }
   handleVerifyWord(e) {
     if (this.value === blacklist[i]) {
       this.refs.input.value = "";
     }
   }
   render() {
     return ( <
       div >
       <
       input type = "text"
       placeholder = {
         this.state.place
       }
       onKeyUp = {
         this.handleVerifyWord.bind(this)
       }
       />< /
       div >
     )
   }
 }
 class getBlackList extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       data: []
     };
   }
   getBlackData() {

   }
 }
 const blacklist = [{
   id: 0,
   name: 'Block'
 }, {
   id: 1,
   name: 'Blocker'
 }]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="blackword"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple things:

1. You should use a ref or e.target.value to get the text content of the input.
2. Instead of `if(e.target.value === blacklist[i])`, you need to check if the item exists anywhere in the array. A way to do this would be `if(blacklist.indexOf(e.target.value) > -1)`
3. If true, you should only replace the value you are testing for:
   `e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(blacklist[i], '')`. You would need to find out what word you are removing first though.